# Fazer soma com SUM()

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Há 2 dias estou batendo cabeça com uma consulta no banco de dados casando tabelas e retornando a soma de valores, consigo executar a *query* pelo PhpMyAdmin tranquilo.

Segue a *query* que funciona no PhpMyAdmin:

```
Select sum(D.CargaHoraria) as CargaHorariaTotal, C.NomeCurso, C.CursoId, A.Imagem
             from Curso C
                  inner join Disciplina D on D.CursoId = C.CursoId
                  inner join Area A on A.AreaId = C.AreaId

             GROUP BY C.CursoId
```

Segue o mesmo codigo no `DB::select` do Laravel e não consigo retorno.

```
DB::select("        
          Select sum(D.CargaHoraria) as CargaHorariaTotal, C.NomeCurso, C.CursoId, A.Imagem
             from Curso C
                  inner join Disciplina D on D.CursoId = C.CursoId
                  inner join Area A on A.AreaId = C.AreaId

             GROUP BY C.CursoId
       ");
```

A intenção e o seguinte, tenho Cursos que cada curso tem varias disciplinas, e cada disciplina tem sua carga horaria, preciso fazer a soma das cargas horarias das disciplinas para obter a `cargaHorariaTotal` do curso.

Mas não estou conseguindo sucesso com o `Laravel`.

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Response;
use App\CursoModel;
use DB;


class CursosController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(CursoModel $objeto)
    {
        //No Auth
        $this->curso = $objeto;
    }

    public function CursosPosGraduacao()
    {

        return view('Cursos/CursosPosGraduacao');
    }

    public function CursosFormacaoPedagogica()
    {
        return view('Cursos/CursosFormacaoPedagogica');
    }

    public function CursosSegundaLicenciatura()
    {
        return view('Cursos/CursosSegundaLicenciatura');
    }

    public function CursoDetalhe()
    {
        return view('Cursos/CursoDetalhe');
    }

    public function retornarTodosOsCursos()
    {
        $Query = DB::select(DB::raw("        
          Select sum(D.CargaHoraria) as CargaHorariaTotal, C.NomeCurso, C.CursoId, A.Imagem
             from Curso C
                  inner join Disciplina D on D.CursoId = C.CursoId
                  inner join Area A on A.AreaId = C.AreaId

             GROUP BY C.CursoId
       "));
        return $Query;
    }
}
```

Route

```
//Matricule
Route::group(['prefix'=>'api'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'Curso'],function(){

        Route::get('retornarTodosOsCursos',['uses'=>'CursosController@retornarTodosOsCursos']);

    });
});
```

CursoModel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Hash;
use Response;
use DB;

class CursoModel extends Model
{
    //
    protected $primaryKey = 'CursoId';
    protected $fillable = ['CursoId', 'AreaId', 'NomeCurso', 'DescricaoCurso', 'ImagemCurso', 'NumeroDoCurso', 'UsuarioId'];
    public $table = 'Curso';


    public function GetAllRepositorio()
    {
        return self::all();
    }

    public function PostRepositorio()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) { //verifica se tem usuario logado
            $data = new CursoModel();
            $data->fill(Input::all());

            if (is_null($data)) {
                return false;
            }

            //Confere se CursoId e maior que 0
            if ($data["CursoId"] > 0) {
                //Envia o registro para Atualizar ja que o mesmo tem CursoId
                $data = $this->AtualizaRegistro($data["CursoId"]);
                //Se salvar retorna true se não retorna falso
                return $data;
            }

            $TodosOsCursos = self::all();
            foreach ($TodosOsCursos as $key => $value) {
                if ($value['NumeroDoCurso'] == $data['NumeroDoCurso'] || $value['NomeCurso'] == $data['NomeCurso']) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            $data['UsuarioId'] = Auth::user()->id;
            return $data->save();
        }
    }

    public function DeletarRepositorio($id)
    {
        $data = self::find($id);
        if (is_null($data)) {
            return false;
        }
        $data->delete();
        return true;
    }

    public function AtualizaRegistro($CursoId)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) { //verifica se tem usuario logado
            //Procura registro no banco pelo $id
            $data = self::find($CursoId);

            //Caso não encontrar registro no banco retorna falso, abortando a operação
            if (is_null($data)) {
                return false;
            }

            //Recebe todos os valores novos que chegaram
            $input = Input::all();

            //Atribui os valores novos no registro 'data' encontrados no banco
            $data->fill($input);

            //Atribui o usuario que executou a ultima ação no registro
            $data['UsuarioId'] = Auth::user()->id;

            //Salva os registros no banco e retorna se atalizou ou não
            return $data->save();


        }
    }

    public function RetornaListaDeCursoPorArea($AreaId){

        $listaDeCursoPorArea = DB::table('Curso')->where('AreaId', $AreaId)->get();
        return $listaDeCursoPorArea;
    }
}
```

Comment: Se você colocar um `dd('Teste')` acima da variável `$Query` e entra no LINK não mostra 'Teste' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Também pode ser o seguinte:

em `config/database.php`:

Altera para isto:

```
...
'strict'=>false
...
```

Para que não coloque como default GROUP na query

Comment: Consigo fazer as somas da Carga Horaria das disciplinas separadas, ele da erro quando adicono algum outro campo a mais no select..

Comment: Tentaste assim como pus em cima? Talvez tenhas de ajustar os nomes dos Models, mas assim seria como eu faria, acho que percebi bem o que queres. Fazer a soma da carga horaria de todas as disciplinas que pertencem a um determinado curso @T.Matoso

Comment: Isso mesmo que preciso, ajustei como você disse em cima as foreign key porém sem sucesso!

Comment: Aparece algum erro? Os nomes dos Models estão certos? @T.Matoso

Comment: @T.Matoso o que aparece se fizeres `dd(Curso::find(1)->disciplinas);` com este modelo que pus em cima? O curso id = 1 tem alguma dics?

Comment: Utilizo API laravel, então não consigo retornar nenhum erro, sei que quando da erro acusa 500 (Internal Server Error) as model estão corretas

Comment: Sabes o que podes fazer, abres a consola, vais à tab network, do lado esquerdo aparece todas a requisições, clicas no primeiro que deve ser o url a que fizeste a requisição, se tiveres no .env DEBUG=TRUE, vai aparecer o html que retorna com o erro @T.Matoso

Comment: Sim, identifiquei aqui pelo network, mas apenas me da um retorno 500(Internal Server Erro) segue o status do retorno com o erro

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8000/api/Curso/retornarTodosOsCursos
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:8000

Comment: Consegues colocar online? Tenta aceder pelo browser mesmo, escreve no URL do navegador: http://localhost:8000/api/Curso/retornarTodosOsCursos a ver o que aparece @T.Matoso

Comment: DA ESSE ERRO!

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'coded362_gestorsite.C.NomeCurso' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: 
Select sum(D.CargaHoraria) as CargaHorariaTotal, C.NomeCurso, C.CursoId, A.Imagem
from Curso C
inner join Disciplina D on D.CursoId = C.CursoId
inner join Area A on A.AreaId = C.AreaId

GROUP BY C.CursoId
)


OPA GOSTEI EIN NÂO SABIA COMO ACHAR O ERRO PELO BROWSER! ! !

Comment: Faz só isso que pus em cima e depois dentro do metodo `retornarTodosOsCursos`, e faz `dd(Curso::find(1)->disciplinas->sum('CargaHoraria'));` a ver o que aparece @T.Matoso

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Curso' not found

Comment: Pois tens de criar o Model para o curso @T.Matoso, não tens model para o curso?

Comment: Vou postar minha model curso em cima, cara voce tem facebook?

Comment: @T.Matoso, editei em cima a resposta de acordo com o nome do teu Model, ajusta o nome do Model das disciplinas também

Answer (score 1):

É preciso fazer um `DB::raw` ou você pode fazer usando Eloquent. A manutenção é melhor no último caso.

### Fluent

```
DB::select(DB::raw("        
          Select sum(D.CargaHoraria) as CargaHorariaTotal, C.NomeCurso, C.CursoId, A.Imagem
             from Curso C
                  inner join Disciplina D on D.CursoId = C.CursoId
                  inner join Area A on A.AreaId = C.AreaId

             GROUP BY C.CursoId
       "));
```

### Eloquent

```
$Query = Curso::join('Disciplina', 'Disciplina.CursoId', '=', 'Curso.CursoId')
              ->join('Area', 'Area.AreaId', '=', 'Curso.AreaId')
              ->selectRaw('SUM(Disciplina.CargaHoraria) AS CargaHorariaTotal, Curso.NomeCurso, Curso.CursoId, Area.Imagem')
              ->groupBy('Curso.CursoId')
              ->get();
```

Todos os campos que irão retornar no AJAX você tem que colocar na variável `$fillable`.

```
protected $fillable = ['CursoId', 'AreaId', 'NomeCurso', 'DescricaoCurso', 'ImagemCurso', 'NumeroDoCurso', 'UsuarioId'];
```

Comment: Campeão, eu tentei fazer desse jeito mas a mesma so funciona se eu retirar os parametros C.NomeCurso e A.Image ficando assim

Comment: Ficando assim
DB::select(DB::raw("        
          Select sum(D.CargaHoraria) as CargaHorariaTotal, C.CursoId
             from Curso C
                  inner join Disciplina D on D.CursoId = C.CursoId
                  inner join Area A on A.AreaId = C.AreaId

             GROUP BY C.CursoId
       "));

Comment: Sim ... os nomes dos campos estão ok, tanto que com o C.CursoId funciona legal..mas se eu inserir C.NomeCurso não funciona.

Comment: Faço uma requisicao por API entao me retorna erro 500 (Internal Server Error) - tem algum jeito de pegar o erro do laravel e retornar?

Comment: Olha, o link está certo, porem quando ele executa a query e gera um erro, ele para e retorna erro 500, tanto que quando coloco a query que funciona, sem todos os parametros ela funciona legal.

Comment: Coloquei true, vou tentar fazer com o dd pra ver se da retorno

Comment: Nada, não volta retorno de erro

Comment: $Query = DB::select(DB::raw("        
          Select sum(D.CargaHoraria) as CargaHorariaTotal, C.CursoId
             from Curso C
                  inner join Disciplina D on D.CursoId = C.CursoId
                  inner join Area A on A.AreaId = C.AreaId

             GROUP BY C.CursoId
       "));

Comment: Tem como você postar seu Controller e seu Route ? Clica no LINK editar abaixo da sua pergunta e coloca lá pra vermos.

Comment: ESSA QUERY NAO FUNCIONA

 $Query = DB::select(DB::raw("        
          Select sum(D.CargaHoraria) as CargaHorariaTotal, C.NomeCurso, C.CursoId, A.Imagem
             from Curso C
                  inner join Disciplina D on D.CursoId = C.CursoId
                  inner join Area A on A.AreaId = C.AreaId

             GROUP BY C.CursoId
       "));